# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE Error 2068 (HY000)

Tags: mysql

I am unable to import csv file to MySQL. The error is as follows:-
ERROR 2068: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.
what to do now. Please help.

Comment: This is client error message. Adjust local access rights (primarily in the filesystem).

Comment: One thing that worked for me is to place the file you want to import in this folder:  `<directory where MySQL is located>/data/<name of your database>`, which in my case is `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data/<name of my database>`.

Comment: Please post your complete statement