# Mysterious MySQL error stops local files from being loaded into tables: "file request rejected due to restrictions on access" (error 2068)

Tags: mysql

I am a new MySQL user trying to follow the introductory tutorial from Oracle.

I was unable to load data into a table from a text file ([this step of the tutorial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/loading-tables.html)).

When I run this line (where `<path>` is a file path):

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "<path>/blob.txt" INTO TABLE blob;
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR 2068 (HY000): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE file request rejected due to restrictions on access.
```

I have tried:

- Placing `blob.txt` into the directory `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data` and using the full path. I used this directory because the variable `datadir` is `/usr/local/mysql/data`.
- Placing `blob.txt` into the aforementioned directory and using only the file name instead of the full path.
- Using and not using `LOCAL`
- Setting `secure-file-priv=''` by creating `~/.my.cn` as described [here](https://geodatawrangler.lazym8.com/blog/2017/02/16/secure-file-priv).
- Setting `local-infile=1`.
- Granting the `FILE` permission.
- Based on one cryptic comment on [a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63127534/load-data-local-infile-error-2068-hy000), I tried changing file permissions. I `chmod 777` -ed the file and its parent directory. But perhaps this needs to be changed for all of the parent directories up the tree, making this an unfeasible solution?

Here's where it gets very strange:

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "blerga blerga blerga bloo" INTO TABLE blob;`

returns *exactly the same error*. That is, it doesn't seem to matter what path I put there. It doesn't even matter whether this is a real path to a real file.

After a few hours of mucking around, **I was able to find one thing that worked:** placing the files inside the folder containing the tables of my database:

`/usr/local/mysql-8.0.21-macos10.15-x86_64/data/dining/blob.txt`

(Dining is the name of the database.) Then loading the data works just fine.

So I am left with wondering:

1. Is this, in fact, the "right" way to do this? Is it safe to be mucking around inside this directory?
2. I'm guessing that this whole problem arose from a file permissions issue. Is that right? I don't really understand this. Is it something like: the server needed access to files on the client side (both of which are on my own computer)?
3. Is there a "correct" way to make it possible to load files from elsewhere in my computer into a table? And if so, are there bad security implications of doing this "in real life" -- with actual servers and clients?

Strangely enough, there quite literally does not seem to be any discussion of this error on the internet, aside from that one lonely comment linked above. There is a [brief listing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/client-error-reference.html#error_cr_load_data_local_infile_rejected) of the error code on the Oracle website, but I haven't found so much as a github comment about this error code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the line/command on how you call the `mysql` client. Also add the output of `SHOW VARIABLES` to your question. And add the output of `mysql --print-defaults`. Specially look for the settings `local-infile` and the very new setting [`load-data-local-dir`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_load-data-local-dir). Also add the content of the mysql client configuration files to your question. Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html for the file paths of these configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is this, in fact, the "right" way to do this? Is it safe to be mucking around inside this directory?

No. You should not go into any internal data structure and mess around with files and directories. A normal user can't do that anyway, only the "root" user can.

> 2. I'm guessing that this whole problem arose from a file permissions issue. Is that right? I don't really understand this. Is it something like: the server needed access to files on the client side (both of which are on my own computer)?

Yes, that is the case. Keep in mind that the MySQL server is running with it's own user account and cannot access all the files on the host. Usually that is not a problem since the server works only inside his assigned data directory.

> 3. Is there a "correct" way to make it possible to load files from elsewhere in my computer into a table? And if so, are there bad security implications of doing this "in real life" -- with actual servers and clients?

The [`LOCAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-file) keyword is used to specify where the file is read from, from the servers perspective or from the clients perspective/host. Usually you use the `LOCAL` keyword to get the file from the host (and perspective) where the mysql client is running.

So you should/must use the `LOCAL` keyword in your query. You do not need the `FILE` permission because you are using the `LOCAL` keyword. See the [`LOAD DATA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html) documentation:

> Using `LOCAL` is a bit slower than letting the server access the files directly, because the file contents must be sent over the connection by the client to the server. On the other hand, you do not need the `FILE` privilege to load local files.

This also means you don't need to change the `secure-file-priv` setting.

Since you use `LOCAL INFILE`, you need the `local-infile` setting enabled. However, you would get a different error message when this setting is disabled.

Comment: I did use the `LOCAL` keyword, and `local-infile` is enabled. Have I misunderstood your answer?